# Defining the predecessor function (with pred 0 = 0) for the natural numbers in Lean

Tags: dependent-type, formal-verification, lean

I'm learning the Lean proof assistant. An exercise in https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/inductive_types.html is to define the predecessor function for the natural numbers. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably familiar with pattern-matching from Lean or some functional programming language, so here is a solution that uses this mechanism:

```
open nat

definition pred : ℕ → ℕ
| zero     := zero
| (succ n) := n
```

Another way of doing this is using a recursor like so:

```
def pred (n : ℕ) : ℕ :=
  nat.rec_on n 0 (λ p _, p)
```

Here, `0` is what we return if the argument is zero and `(λ p _, p)` is an anonymous function that takes two arguments: the predecessor (`p`) of `n` and the result of recursive call `pred p`. The anonymous function ignores the second argument and returns the predecessor.